# How to implement SSO in normal ASP.NET 4.5 application using OKTA as Identity provider

Tags: asp.net, saml, okta

Im having a normal ASP.net application. I need to enable SSO in my login screen. I have Identity provider as OKTA. We have got the meta data file from OKTA and im not sure how to use it in our application and enable SSO. Not sure if any coding is required. Really appreciate your support on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use our commercial [SAML library](https://www.componentspace.com/saml-for-asp-net) which supports SSO with Okta and any other SAML compliant identity provider. For more information, refer to our [Okta Integration Guide](https://www.componentspace.com/documentation/saml-for-asp-net/integrations/ComponentSpace%20Okta%20Integration%20Guide.pdf).

There are also open source implementations available as well.